# calling asynchronous recursive function in loop and getting result in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise, deferred

Due to a weird API, I need to call asynchronous recursive function in loop and getting result in angularJS. Below is example of my situation.

We have task lists, each Task may have none, one or more Sub Tasks
Each Sub Tasks may further have none, one or more Sub Tasks
I need to get all Tasks and Sub Tasks in a single array of objects
The problem is for getting the list of Sub Tasks of a Task, we need to call async API.
Due to async in nature of API, I was not able to get all result

```
 //We have task lists
allTasks = fromSomeOtherFuncion();
$scope.loadSubTask = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        for (var j = 0; j < allTasks.length; j++) {

            for (var k = 0; k < allTasks[j].subtasks.length; k++) {
                $scope.fetchTaskByTaskID(allTasks[j].subtasks[k].id, deferred);
            }
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    $scope.fetchTaskByTaskID = function (id, deferred) {
        if (!deferred) {
            deferred = $q.defer();
        }
        var client = window.client;
        client.tasks.findById(id, {
            opt_fields: 'id,name,memberships,subtasks',
        }).then(function (response) {

            if (response.subtasks.length > 0) {
                for (var m = 0; m < response.subtasks.length; m++) {
                    $scope.fetchTaskByTaskID(response.subtasks[m].id, deferred);
                }
            }
            else {
                deferred.resolve(response);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        });
    };

//Then I called the function
 $scope.loadSubTask().then(function (subtasks) {
                        //I need here all Tasks+SubTasks+SubSubTasks..., which I am not getting


                    });
```

Comment: you are not aggregating the tasks as you are getting them. keep pushing them in an array as you loop through the subtasks or as you get them asynchronously and then finally resolve that array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to preserve the value of j and K. You can do this way:

```
$scope.loadSubTask = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        for (var j = 0; j < allTasks.length; j++) {
         (function(j){

            for (var k = 0; k < allTasks[j].subtasks.length; k++) {
               (function(k){

                $scope.fetchTaskByTaskID(allTasks[j].subtasks[k].id, deferred);
             })(k)
            }
         })(j)
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

> You can also use let instead of var. It will be the most cleaner way,

Comment: Hi Ved, Thanks for suggestion. But my problem not got solved. For understanding my sitattion, I have created plunkr. I need the callback when all async requests get executed.
http://plnkr.co/edit/6pZ6gHIbdg0tI02PAeIS